# How manage user privileges in Portal for ArcGIS (operational dashboard)

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-portal, operations-dashboard

I am working on Operations Dashboard using Portal for ArcGIS. Different users have different spatial extent (different district). User name and District Data in PostgreSQL table. Now my issue is how to customize their dashboard based on their required district?

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate dashboard for each extent and use a corresponding base layer and associated district layers.